# text replacement using psfrag in the .eps format

Tags: psfrag

Can anyone tell how one can use the text replacement using psfrag in the .eps format of 3 dimensional matlab plot?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
      \psfrag{P_dbm}[cc][cc][0.7]{$P_{dBm}$}
 \psfrag{t_l}[cc][cc][0.7]{$\ti$}
  \psfrag{f_k}[cc][cc][0.7]{$\fk$}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Fig4}
\caption{Measured data}
\label{fig:offroomii28}

\end{figure}
```

here is the code in latex.the figure is in .eps format. which i saved from matlab as eps which is 3 dimensional plot.the point is, in 2 dimensional plot. psfrag is working absolutely fine and replace the text but in 3 dimensional plot  psfrag is not working..like the text remain the same on axis as it was in eps format.text replacement is not done by psfrag

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @close-voter(s): This question is at the moment not clear, but it's too early to close it yet.

Comment: \begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
      \psfrag{P_dbm}[cc][cc][0.7]{$P_{dBm}$}
 \psfrag{t_l}[cc][cc][0.7]{$\ti$}
  \psfrag{f_k}[cc][cc][0.7]{$\fk$}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Fig4}
\caption{Measured ISM data traffic in the office room}
\label{fig:offroomii28}

\end{figure}

Comment: does the literal string `(f_k)` appear in the EPS file matlab generated, and does you tex document define `\fk`, if both of those are true your code should probably work (but psfrag makes some assumptions about the postscript that are not always true)

Comment: i think the problem is not that string i made it using tex command \fk. bt even i tried with plain texts.it did not replace.i also assumed if it works fine for 2 dimensional plot, it should work with 3 dimensional plot... what kind of assumptions.can you please clear it.

Comment: Maybe Matlab puts a space in front or back of the string (that is, `( f_k)` or `(f_k )`)?

Comment: this i already chk with plain text..even when i opened the code of .eps in matlab.. i cnt find that text to see whether that kind of problem is there

Comment: @khurram psfrag makes simple redefinition of the postscript `show` primitive  it only works if text is displayed via the complete string being shown via `show` (and some related commands) if the postscript tries to be fancy and splits the text up character by character to kern or position "by hand" psfrag won't see the string, if various assorted or new postscript scoping mechanisms are used to protect the postscript definitions on the file, the psfrag definitions may have no effect but normally if you see the string `(f_k)` as unencoded text in the EPS file, it works.

Comment: @khurram If you can not find the text `(f_k)` in the EPS file, then psfrag won't be able to find it either.

Comment: if i understood well, its problem of matlab conversion of 3d plot into .eps.. for this is there any tool where i open eps file write a text dere n replace it with psfrag..in inkscape the problem is until version 0.44 i cannt open .eps file while in later version if i can open .eps file bt the text in eps is not recognized in psfrag... any solution?

Comment: The psfrag documentation advises to try simpler (1-letter) labels in such a case, if f_k is not in the eps try making a matlab label with one letter eg f and see if you can replace that

Comment: no 1-letter labels are not working here too.. :(... can any1 have a soltuion about the problem i described in above comment.